# Como se traduz "scope" se tratando de desenvolvimento de software?

Tags: tradução-inglês, diferenças-transatlânticas

No contexto de desenvolvimento de software no Brasil, "scope" é comumente traduzido como "escopo" (curiosamente, é uma palavra bem pouco usada no Brasil em outras situações).

A tradução é corroborada por estes links da Wikipedia:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)

[https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escopo_(computação)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escopo_(computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o))

Deste último, destaco estes trechos:

> *Em Ciência da Computação escopo é um contexto delimitante aos quais valores e expressões estão associados (...) Normalmente, o escopo é utilizado para definir o grau de ocultação da informação, isto é, a visibilidade e acessibilidade às variáveis em diferentes partes do programa.*

Ocorre que, em uma conversa recente em um grupo de programadores, um participante de Portugal mencionou que em pt_PT não é comum esse uso da palavra "escopo".

Isto procede? Quais seriam as possíveis traduções para o termo? "Escopo" neste contexto é comum em outros países lusófonos que não o Brasil?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eu estive a perguntar a uns programadores portugueses e chegamos a um consenso. Curiosamente parece que a resposta está na pergunta:

> Em Ciência da Computação ***escopo é um contexto*** delimitante aos quais
>   valores e expressões estão associados (...) Normalmente, o escopo é
>   utilizado para definir o grau de ocultação da informação, isto é, a
>   visibilidade e acessibilidade às variáveis em diferentes partes do
>   programa.

Ainda mais curioso, ao pesquisar por exemplos de contexto encontrei no [github de um professor da Universidade Federal da Bahia](https://rodrigorgs.github.io/aulas/mata56/aula13-js-closures):

> O ***contexto*** ou ambiente de referenciamento de uma região de um programa
>   corresponde ao conjunto de vinculações que pode-se acessar naquela
>   região.

Reparem que neste segundo trecho ele tanto refere contexto como escopo:

> Para buscar a variável xext, o interpretador Javascript primeiro
>   procura nas variáveis definidas dentro da função interna. Não
>   encontrando, ele vai procurar variáveis definidas no ***contexto*** da
>   função externa. Se ainda não encontrar, procura nas variáveis globais.
>   Ou seja, o ambiente de referenciamento inclui o ***escopo*** atual e mais
>   todos os escopos externos.

Em Portugal encontrei um documento da Universidade de Lisboa com a utilização de contexto:

> Se a função alterar o conteúdo da tabela, essa alteração tem efeitos
>   fora do ***contexto*** da função.

Ao pesquisar no Google por «contexto da função» encontrei tanto resultados em pt_PT como em pt_BR. Ao que parece também se usa no Brasil a palavra ***contexto*** para essa situação. Não sei se será regional ou não.

Comment: achou a palavra que estava pensando... parabéns pela resposta!

Answer (score 2):

"Scope" em termos mais gerais poderia ser traduzido com "âmbito" em portugal.

Não sendo programador, do que entendi da explicação penso que se possa aplicar neste caso como o âmbito em que determinado nome ou designação de uma entidade é válido ou acessível. "Abrangência" ou "limite" também me parecem sinónimos aceitáveis.

Escopo não é de todo uma palavra comum em linguagem corrente (primeira vez que a leio para dizer a verdade), mas pode igualmente ser definida como [abrangência ou limite](https://dicionario.priberam.org/escopo).